# return two values from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, return

Is is possible to return two values from a WebService to jQuery.

I tried like

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string testing(string testId)
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    string data1 = string.Empty;
    List<test1> datalist1 = new List<test1>();
    List<test> datalist = new List<test>();

    //coding
    data = jsonSerialize.Serialize(datalist1);
    data1 = jsonSerialize.Serialize(datalist);
    return [data,data1];
}
```

but its showing error....how can we return two values from webservice here.....

Comment: There are two syntax errors in your example code, so I'm not surprised you're seeing an error. Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: look at your code... you starting with **public string** and what you returning??? To return multiple values you should return an array of values.

Comment: sorry sixlettervariables and huMpty duMpty its not my actual code, I just wanted to know that returning more than one value from the webservice is possible or not, thats what I've shown a sample program here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like

```
 return jsonSerialize.Serialize(new { list1 = datalist1, list = datalist });
```

and I can receive these from my jQuery file easily. Thanks everyone for ur support

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to create a custom data type that has the two return values you want:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public MyData testing(string testId)
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    string data1 = string.Empty;
    List<test1> datalist1 = new List<test1>();
    List<test> datalist = new List<test>();

    //coding
    data = jsonSerialize.Serialize(datalist1);
    data1 = jsonSerialize.Serialize(datalist);
    return new MyData { Data = data, Data1 = data1 };
}
```

**OR**

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyData
{
    public List<test> Data { get; set; }
    public List<test1> Data1 { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string testing(string testId)
{
    MyData data = new MyData();
    string alldata = string.Empty;
    List<test1> datalist1 = new List<test1>();
    List<test> datalist = new List<test>();

    //coding
    data.Data = datalist1;
    data.Data1 = datalist;
    alldata = jsonSerialize.Serialize(data);
    return alldata;
}
```

Comment: thanks Jesse, actully we've declared the method as type String, it shows the conversion error, and how can I receive these two values in my jQuery??

Comment: actually I need to display the records in data and data1 seperately, thats what am passing these two here, I tried Jon Skeet's solution, its working, but I dunno how to receive this array value in jQuery, I tried receiving like "success: function (data,data1) {" ......its showing error

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowledgeable in jQuery, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Well you could return an *array* of strings:

```
public string[] Testing(...)
{
    return new string[] { data, data1 };
}
```

You'd then need to perform each bit of JSON deserialization separately on the client, which isn't likely to be terribly pleasant :(

Comment: thanks Jon its working....how can I receive these two values in the jQuery, if its a single value I can receive like "success: function (data) {"

Comment: @Shanish: I would expect you to be able to use `data[0]` and `data[1]`. But I can't say I've done any JSON/jQuery work...

Comment: @JonSkeet - C# 4 seen the introduction of returning Tuple from a method - can that be used somehow here Jon?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: I don't know how that would be represented in a web service response. Maybe it would work - I don't know.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Interesting, I know little about web services but I do understand that there's certain complexities with serialization so I'll look into this. I think it's best you ignore my comment of tuple's though for now Shanish.

Answer (score 1):

`return [data, data1]` is not valid C# syntax. If you want to return a JSON array to the caller, use the `JsonSerializer` to serialize the array and return the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

a webmethod is like a regular method, it can only return **one** value.

if its the same type you can use a list or array.

if its different types you can make a class holding the data