# How to return more than a string from a webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, web-services

I have made webservice in asp.net using C# and MySQL. I want to return multiple values from this service. I am using the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string RegisterUserViaFacebook(string fbid, string fbmailid,string devicetype)  
{
    string success = "Already Registered";
    string id="", name="";

    if (!ExistsFBID(fbid))
    {
        name = GenerateUserName();

        string password = generatePassword(10);

        string insertUser = "Insert into tbl_userinfo(UserName,Password,Facebook_ID,Facebook_EmailID,DeviceType) values";
        insertUser += "( '" + name + "' ,'" + password + "','" + fbid + "','" + fbmailid + "','" + devicetype + "' )";
        con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertUser, con);
        success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        con.Close();

        string getID = "SELECT UserID from tbl_userinfo where UserName='" + name + "'  ";
        con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(getID, con);
        id = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();


        if (Convert.ToInt16(success) > 0)
        {
            SendMail(fbmailid, name, password);
            success = "New User"  ;
        }
        else
            success = "Error in Insertion";
    }
    else
    {
        string getID1 = "SELECT UserID, UserName from tbl_userinfo where Facebook_ID='" + fbid + "' ";
        con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(getID1, con);
        MySqlDataReader info = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (info.Read())
        {
            id = info.GetString(0);
            name = info.GetString(1);

        }
        con.Close();
    }

    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(success);
    String finalString = "{\"USER IS\":";
    finalString += jsonString;
    finalString += "}";

    string jsonString1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
    String finalString1 =finalString + "{\"ID IS\":";
    finalString1 += jsonString1;
    finalString1 += "}" ;

    string jsonString2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(name);
    String finalString2 = finalString1 + "{\"NAME IS\":";
    finalString2 += jsonString2;
    finalString2 += "}";
    return finalString2;


 }
```

But it returns all values in single string. I want to return the values individually as `Succeess`, `ID` and `Name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you return the value as an **array** ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - thanks for reply. Can you please guide how to do that?

Comment: Why are you manually crafting SQL and JSON? There's tons of libraries out there that do the same with less code and less potential for error.

Comment: Whats consuming your web service? does it need to return Json?

Comment: @Liam - ya it needs to return Json

Comment: @RKP: Have a look at this question which might help you : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192356/return-two-values-from-webservice**

Comment: I get the feeling you could do with reading up on what JSON is. It's JavaScript Object Notation. The important thing to note here is object. So JSON is a string but it's a way to describe an object. so you can return any object you want in it, and that object can contain as many values as you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a simple class to hold Succeess, id and name and return an serialized instance of it.

```
public class RegistrationResult
{
   public string Success { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You could do this:

```
var result = new RegistrationResult { Success = success, Name = name, Id = id} ;
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(success);
```

Comment: If you don't want to create a class u could use out parameters. But i would prefer the class. Just for your information

Comment: @geon - But _to_ serialize into JSON to begin with, you would need a proper object to hold all these values.

Comment: @Oded - thanks for reply. But how can i do this ? I have no idea to use it. Please help me.

Comment: @Oded - i have used your code but shows that Success, Name, and ID is inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: @RKP - Then just make them public. I updated my answer, in case you don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return a singel object in the JSON.

```
return "{user: "+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(success)+", id: "+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id)+", name: "+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(name)+"}";
```

The answer by Oded is fine too. It's a bit more clear, but also needs an extra class.