# Return two values from webservice without Result tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, return, asmx

I have similar question to [return two values from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10192356/5126433). Above methods works, but structure of response is:

```
  <soap:Body>
    <testingResponse xmlns="http://test.local/">
      <testingResult>
        <Data>string</Data>
        <Data1>string</Data1>
      </testingResult>
    </testingResponse>
  </soap:Body>
```

But how can I get response structure like:

```
  <soap:Body>
    <testingResponse xmlns="http://test.local/">
      <Data>string</Data>
      <Data1>string</Data1>
    </testingResponse>
  </soap:Body>
```